# Can I use xterm to read/write to a pts without spawning another process (e.g a shell)?

Tags: linux, terminal, console, tty

I have a process which reads and writes to a pseudo terminal.  I would like to open xterm and have it open a pseudo terminal and leave it open so I can communicate with this process without creating yet another process.

Right now I use the following hack.  I create a trivial program:

```
void main() {while(1);}
```

and then I open it in an xterm window like this:

```
xterm ~/a.out
```

Then I can write to the other process and read its output on the xterm window.  Is there any way I can do this without having xterm spawn some useless process?

Edit: The process I am trying to communicate with is an operating system which is running inside the Bochs emulator.  I am trying to connect the serial port on the emulated system with a pseudo terminal on the host system.  I specify the particular pseudo terminal in the Bochs configuration file like this:

```
com1: enabled=1, mode=term,dev=/dev/pts/4
```

Comment: I'm confused: what is preventing you from using `xterm your_app`, so that the application has the pseudo terminal bound to its stdin/out/err?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't - it is actually the way recommended in the `bochsrc` man page. If you are worried about the extra process, you can spawn this instead of your trivial loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("tty:  %s\n", ttyname(0));
    while (1)
        sleep(60);
    return 0;
}
```

You'll get the tty name and the `sleep()` ensures that you don't waste precious SPU time in a trivial busy loop. You could also use `pause()` instead of `sleep()`.

Or you can patch Xterm, it's open-source after all.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little surprised it's not possible.  I don't really have to use xterm.  If there is another terminal emulator that will do this, that would work too.

Comment: You can try other terminals, but I'd be a bit sceptical - running programs inside of them is the main raison d'être of terminals. :)